# How do you display a video on autoplay without any control in NextJS 14?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

How do you display a video on autoplay without any control in NextJS 14? I am managing to get it to work but only with the play button to activate it. Autoplay isn't working?

Here is my component code:

```
function Hero() {
 
  return (
    <div className="w-full h-screen">
      <video
        loop
        playsInline
        muted
        autoPlay
        className="w-full h-screen object-cover"
      >
        <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Hero;
```

I am trying to get the video to work automatically full screen. Currently it works with a play button only.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach if works.

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

function Hero() {
  const videoRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const video = videoRef.current;

    if (video) {
      video.muted = true;

      try {
        video.play();
      } catch (error) {
        console.warn('Autoplay failed:', error);
      }

      if (video.requestFullscreen) {
        video.requestFullscreen();
      } else if (video.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        video.webkitRequestFullscreen();
      } else if (video.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        video.mozRequestFullScreen();
      }
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="w-full h-screen">
      <video
        ref={videoRef}
        loop
        playsInline
        muted
        autoPlay
        className="w-full h-screen object-cover"
      >
        <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Hero;
```